# create a table with dates in a specific format as columns

Tags: r

I want to create a table (wither data frame or data table) with two columns and 30 rows which are actualy dates.
Col1 should contain dates like: yyyymm between 199801 and 200012 in this particular format and randomly generated. Col2 should get only the year information from the first column.

I tried with as.Date but I didn't get teh format above.
Any clue how toget it right?
Thank you

Comment: The Date data type will always print in the standard format `YYYY-MM-DD`. You could randomly generate your dates and then use `strftime` to convert to the desired format, but it won't be possible to alter the formatting while also preserving the underlying Date type.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
set.seed(1234)
dates <- (sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 30))
data.frame(Col1 = format.Date(dates,"%Y%m"),
           Col2 = format.Date(dates,"%Y"))

     Col1 Col2
1  201805 2018
2  201805 2018
3  200107 2001
4  200506 2005
5  200402 2004
6  201102 2011
7  200203 2002
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. it works out. May I ask you another question ? Suppose I have the above table where Col1 represent always  the year and month and they are  actualy characters type. Additionaly, I have a column Col3  (numerical)  and need to make some operations on it like: summing up everything yearly based or  monthly based. How would that work?

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like should use a string in Col1. Are you parsing this from dates from another source (csv?, excel?)

Col2 can then just use `substr`:

```
dat <- data.frame(col1 = c("201812", "201901"))
dat %>% 
  mutate(
    col2 = substr(col1, 1,4)
  )
```

Comment: Thank you very much. it works out. May I ask you another question ? Suppose I have the above table where Col1 represent always the year and month and they are actualy characters type. Additionaly, I have a column Col3 (numerical) and need to make some operations on it like: summing up everything yearly based or monthly based. How would that work?

Comment: I'd suggest using the `dplyr` package for that. Summarizing per year and month would then be: `dat %>% group_by(col1, col2) %>% summarise(col3Summed = sum(col3))`